# dns points to wrong directory

Tags: apache

I'm trying to setup two virtual hosts in windows using xampp. From what I've read one have to alter the windows hosts file and xampp's httpd-vhosts.conf file.

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       gholizadeh
127.0.0.1       doostr
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

vhosts file:

```
    NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost gholizadeh>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey\pappa"
    ServerName gholizadeh.se
    ServerAlias www.gholizadeh.se
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey\pappa">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost doostr>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey"
    ServerName doostr.com
    ServerAlias www.doostr.com
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost localhost>
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp"
    ServerName localhost
    <Directory "E:\xampp">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I'm having problem accessing these files. When I try it from my own LAN I get prompted to the xampp site and when get access denied when trying to enter it from extern network. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: DNS entries _never_ point to a directory. They resolve host names to ip addresses, not more. Also, it looks like you make this setup for your LAN only, since you add non-routable addresses and host entries without domain names. In that case you don't use DNS anyway, but just plain host lookups.

Comment: Not sure, but it might be that you missunderstood how DNS name resolution works: your example is a mixture of internal and external setup. If you want to serve real web pages you need a DNS entry which is nothing you can do by modifying local files like your host file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `VirtualHost` command wrong. Use it like this instead:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gholizadeh.se
    ServerAlias www.gholizadeh.se
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey\pappa"
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey\pappa">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName doostr.com
    ServerAlias www.doostr.com
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey"
    <Directory "E:\xampp\htdocs\lowkey">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "E:\xampp"
    <Directory "E:\xampp">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Some more things: 
* you should add a `ServerAdmin`to each host
* the entries in the host file are just for internal debugging purposes, I assume?

And a side remark: 
you don't plan to serve real web pages in the internet from this MS-Windows system, do you?

Comment: No nothing serious that I'm going public with. Its just for learning purposes/showcase. Thanks for the help. Could you please explain what the difference is between *:80 and explicitlity stating the host name? I've read/followed the guide at: http://austinpassy.com/tutorials/setting-up-virtual-hosts-wordpress-multisite-with-xampp-on-windows-7/